Customizing Bitbucket Copy to Clipboard Commands
I am trying to customize the copy branch name to clipboard to include git commands. When I create a branch in bitbucket successfully I am led to this page where I am given the option to copy branch name.
Screenshot of branch creation page
This was previously configured by someone no longer working on this project to include "git checkout  [branch_name]" and I would like to make changes to that git command but I cannot find it anywhere in settings.
Is anyone out there with more experience in Bitbucket than me who can lend some guidance on where to find this configuration?
I have searched through settings in my specific repo, and project to no avail. Searches of this site and Google have not led me to a productive answer

Is this server or cloud? And why do you think that is customized? On cloud that is the default AFAIK

This is bitbucket cloud. I assumed it was customized because when I first started on this project we had this clipboard command as "git fetch && git checkout" which is what I was hoping to change it back to, but maybe the default was changed by bitbucket at some point if this is not customizable?
